# Xamarin.Forms App Crash in Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, out-of-memory

What is the issue which will cause the app crash when a user opens the app?

I integrate with HockeyApp, the error shown:

> **VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray** java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 63701004 byte allocation with 16777056 free bytes and 41MB
>   until OOM

```
Xamarin caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 63701004 byte
allocation with 16777056 free bytes and 41MB until OOM
dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal()BitmapFactory.java:639
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream()BitmapFactory.java:615
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream()BitmapFactory.java:653
```

**Answer**
I already solve the problems with

1. Update the Xamarin.Forms Nuget.
2. Delete the package file in the solution.
3. Build the Solution again.

Comment: OutOfMemoryError is fairly self explanatory

Comment: Could you show us relevant code where the error occurs?

Comment: @zett42 update with description

Comment: You can try to set the Heap size in Android Project -> Properties -> Android  Options -> Linker and Set the Heap Size `1G`

Comment: @ChandreshKhambhayata the Linker set to None?

Comment: Sorry, it's not `Linker` it's `Advanced` and `Java Max Heap Size`

Answer (score 2):

Add in your manifest these lines `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` , `android:largeHeap="true"` it may solve your issue(s).

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It turned out that multiple changes solved the problem.

Firstly, I ensured that my app can **deal with large memory heaps**. This is a setting you can set/change in the app's manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:largeHeap="true"> <!-- This line does the trick. -->
```

Secondly, I made sure that I **enforce small image sizes** wherever possible. In my case I decided to limit the max resolution to either 720 pixels or the screen resolution, whatever is *smaller*. As a result I resized large images:

```
int maxImageSideLength = Math.Min(720, Math.Max(myScreenHeight, myScreenWidth));
// see tutorials how to resize the image now
```

Lastly, I ensured to **dispose image bitmaps** (used memory) that where assigned to image views before I assigned a new image. I am uncertain whether this is really necessary as I can't believe that assigning a new image bitmap isn't cleaned up properly, but I left this in my code and I am still happy with a smoothly running app. Example:

```
Bitmap resizedImage = ResizeImage(fileName, maxImageSideLength);
imageView.SetImageBitmap(null); // this is to free allocated memory
imageView.SetImageBitmap(resizedImage);
GC.Collect(); // dispose of the Java side bitmap
```